Bitvise SSh Client connection disconnected on user request while using stnlc.exe
I am using following command line utility stnlc.exe to connect to SSH server that is on Window Server 2019 from window 7
stnlc -profile="stf_profile.tlp"
connection disconnect after displaying "Connection disconnected on user's request."
But if i use same profile ("stf_profile.tlp") through Bitvise SSh Client it connect successfully
Complete log using stnlc
Connection established.
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_9.5
First key exchange started. Cryptographic provider: Windows CNG (x86) with
additions
Received host key from the server. Algorithm: RSA/sha2-512, size: 3072 bits,
SHA-256 fingerprint: NJnUkhzvpPBJEV85GxvoOufXq+nS2bqkMcSa5sWGy3U.
First key exchange completed using Curve25519 (strict). Connection encryption
and integrity: aes256-gcm, compression: none.
Attempting publickey authentication. Testing client key 'Profile 1' for
acceptance.
The client key 'Profile 1' has been accepted.
Attempting publickey authentication. Signing with client key 'Profile 1' using
rsa-sha2-512.
Authentication completed.
Added client-to-server port forwarding rule on 127.0.0.1:3381 to localhost:3388.
ERROR: Failed to invite server-configured client-to-server port forwardings:
Operation was rejected.
Connection disconnected on user's request.
